# Error when i deploy war (TomCat)

Tags: maven-2, tomcat, deployment, m2eclipse

when i deploy my war into TomCat i have this error:

> 14 sept. 2010 11:48:07
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   filterStart GRAVE: Exception au
>   démarrage du filtre struts2 Unable to
>   load bean: type:
>   class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory
>   - bean - jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%206.0/webapps/tuto-hello/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:131)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   Caused by: Bean type class
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory
>   with the name xwork has already been
>   loaded by bean -
>   jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%206.0/webapps/tuto-hello/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:30:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%206.0/webapps/tuto-hello/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:193)
>     ... 33 more 14 sept. 2010 11:48:08
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: ContextListener:
>   contextInitialized() 14 sept. 2010
>   11:48:08
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: SessionListener:
>   contextInitialized()

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>monTest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>monTest Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>              
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
      <profile>
      <id>default-tools.jar</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
  <build>
    <finalName>monTest</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
             <configuration>
                <update>true</update>            
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html</url>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>root</password>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several versions of struts2-core (struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar and struts2-core-2.2.1.jar) on your classpath. You need to do some cleanup. Show your complete pom.xml for more help.

Comment: i use struts2-core-2.2.1.jar in my POM.xml

Comment: @Scandalous Maybe. But that's still what the `Caused by:` is saying. Did you try to do a `mvn clean install`? Maybe you had some cruft in the target directory.